# How to specify encoding bitrate while capturing from a webcam - MS Expression Encoder 4

Tags: webcam, bitrate, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I have a program to capture and save live webcam video.
This is taken from sample programs coming with Expression Encoder 4.

```
LiveJob job = new LiveJob();
EncoderDevice video = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video).Count > 0 ? EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video)[0] : null;
EncoderDevice audio = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio).Count > 0 ? EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio)[0] : null;

LiveDeviceSource deviceSource = job.AddDeviceSource(video, audio);
job.ActivateSource(deviceSource);

//When the Start Encoding Button is clicked.
fileOut.OutputFileName = "C:\\output\\Capture\\Video1.wmv";
job.PublishFormats.Add(fileOut);
job.StartEncoding();

//When the Stop Encoding Button is clicked.
job.StartEncoding();
```

How to specify the bitrate of the encoded video.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add format

```
WindowsMediaOutputFormat outputFormat = new WindowsMediaOutputFormat();  
AdvancedVC1VideoProfile profile = new AdvancedVC1VideoProfile();  
profile.Bitrate = 1;  
outputFormat.VideoProfile = profile;  
job.OutputFormat = outputFormat;
```