# Live Smooth Streaming:Point To Start

Tags: c#, video-streaming, smooth-streaming

I want to do simple live broadcast from iphone (or any other device, webcam for example).I have read a lot of articles and next view was formed for me:

- The video before broadcasting must be encoded.
- Video can be accessed at specifyed streaming address.

[This](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CE8QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FA%2FA%2FB%2FAABEB56E-45B7-4145-BDB1-595DE745F61F%2FSMEast2010-Microsoft.pdf&ei=D1QlUc-fGImYtQbY3IGwDw&usg=AFQjCNHaDoBXYcSmQbjicpE9tg9tyHPP1g&sig2=N80VCzFS4_VfPxKK0atIjQ&bvm=bv.42661473,d.Yms&cad=rja) "presentation" shows the whole arhitecture

[This](http://www.iis.net/learn/media/on-demand-smooth-streaming/getting-started-with-iis-smooth-streaming) simple example shows how to broadcast from static content (video file that lies on server)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879049/how-to-specify-encoding-bitrate-while-capturing-from-a-webcam-ms-expression-en) question shows how to start encoding

But I cant link all together (and this articles doesnt contain much code) - How to deal with "online" video - I just need few lines of code to understand this.Must I create any TCP channels or something else?Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You have C# tagged in this question, yet your platform is the iPhone, notorious for its unforgiving licensing agreement for development with regards to the what language you can use. I would personally recommend you use the new HTML5/JS stuff. There is everything you need there from WebSockets (http://html5demos.com/web-socket) to Html Video Capture(http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this http://blog.gingertech.net/2012/06/04/video-conferencing-in-html5-webrtc-via-web-sockets/

It shows a fully working node.js server backend with a HTML5 WebRTC client to create a video conferencing demo.